Replacement for 'enum class' with string functionality
Because I think maintainability can be done better with strings instead of plain enumerator-values when doing fstream IO, I wanted a replacement struct in my project that behaves like an enum class but provides string functionality. It turned out to be a project on its own.  There are other implementations to achieve this kind of functionality, but for me it's also a learning process. Three generic questions:

What did I miss in trying to mimic enum class behavior (see main())?
What rules did I break, things I forgot, when putting this code together (I do not
see myself as a very good programmer, happy when things just work...)?
I read somewhere to use noexcept wherever possible. Is that a correct practice?

Other question: I have the following:
    // Conversion operator, used for static_cast.
    explicit operator T() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

Would it be better to have this templated itself like:
    // Conversion operator, used for static_cast.
    template<class U>
    explicit operator U() const noexcept {
        return static_cast<U>(value);
    }

If this is not the right place or format, please let me know.
Required: C++20, and /Zc:preprocessor for MSVC++ (which I used). Code is in one file now for simplicity.
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The folowing set of macros was written by David Mazières:
//
//      https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html
// 
// I added prefix 'EB_' to prevent name-collisions with other macros.
// 
// Note: In MSVC++ you need the switch '/Zc:preprocessor'. 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// These expand macros enable over 300 arguments for FOR_EACH.
#define EB_EXPAND(...)  EB_EXPAND4(EB_EXPAND4(EB_EXPAND4(EB_EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EB_EXPAND4(...) EB_EXPAND3(EB_EXPAND3(EB_EXPAND3(EB_EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EB_EXPAND3(...) EB_EXPAND2(EB_EXPAND2(EB_EXPAND2(EB_EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EB_EXPAND2(...) EB_EXPAND1(EB_EXPAND1(EB_EXPAND1(EB_EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EB_EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

// A set of parens.
#define EB_PARENS   ()

// The actual FOR_EACH macro.
#define EB_FOR_EACH(macro, ...)                                    \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_EXPAND(EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER(macro, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER(macro, a1, ...)                         \
  macro(a1)                                                        \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN EB_PARENS (macro, __VA_ARGS__))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN() EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// My own code starts here.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Macro: count ___VA_ARGS__.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define EB_COUNT_VA_ARGS_PLUS_ONE(dummy)    +1
#define EB_COUNT_VA_ARGS(...)               0 EB_FOR_EACH(EB_COUNT_VA_ARGS_PLUS_ONE, __VA_ARGS__)

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FOR_EACH variant: fixed argument 1 (FA1 = Fix Arg 1) for the macro. Used
// for generating names-pairs like
// 
//      "Smaller", "Enum::Smaller",
//      "Greater", "Enum::Greater",
// 
// where "Enum" is the fixed argument for the macro that generates each line.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The FOR_EACH macro with a fixed first argument (FA1 = Fix Arg 1) for the processing macro.
#define EB_FOR_EACH_FA1(macro, fix1, ...)                                    \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_EXPAND(EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA1(macro, fix1, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA1(macro, fix1, arg, ...)                        \
  macro(fix1, arg)                                                           \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN_FA1 EB_PARENS (macro, fix1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN_FA1() EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA1

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FOR_EACH variant: fixed arguments 1 and 2, plus a counter (FA12_CNT = Fix
// Arg 1/2, plus a CNT). Called by macro 'EB_GENERATE_ENUMERATORS'.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT_PLUS_ONE(cnt)              cnt+1
#define EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT(macro, fix1, fix2, ...)    EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT_WORKER(macro, fix1, fix2, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
#define EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT_WORKER(macro, fix1, fix2, cnt, ...)                            \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_EXPAND(EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA12_CNT(macro, fix1, fix2, cnt, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA12_CNT(macro, fix1, fix2, cnt, arg, ...)                       \
  macro(fix1, fix2, cnt, arg)                                                               \
  __VA_OPT__(EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN_FA12_CNT EB_PARENS (macro, fix1, fix2, EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT_PLUS_ONE(cnt), __VA_ARGS__))
#define EB_FOR_EACH_AGAIN_FA12_CNT() EB_FOR_EACH_HELPER_FA12_CNT

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Macros to build the enum-struct.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Macro that generates an enumerator as a struct-member with the correct value.
#define EB_GENERATE_ENUMERATOR(eb_type, eb_enum, eb_value, eb_name)  static inline constexpr EnumBuilderEnumerator<eb_type, eb_enum> eb_name = GetWrappedValue(static_cast<eb_type>(eb_value));
#define EB_GENERATE_ENUMERATORS(eb_type, eb_enum, ...)  EB_FOR_EACH_FA12_CNT(EB_GENERATE_ENUMERATOR, eb_type, eb_enum, __VA_ARGS__) 

// Macro that generates a pair of names.
#define EB_GENERATE_NAMES_PAIR(eb_enum, eb_name)  #eb_name, #eb_enum"::"#eb_name, 

// This is the macro that builds that 'enum class'.
#define ENUM_CLASS_BUILDER(eb_type, eb_enum, ...)                                                      \
struct eb_enum final : public EnumBuilderBase<eb_type, eb_enum> {                                      \
    eb_enum() : EnumBuilderBase(EnumBuilderEnumerator<eb_type, eb_enum>::invalid_value) {}             \
    eb_enum(const EnumBuilderEnumerator<eb_type, eb_enum>& e) : EnumBuilderBase(e) {}                  \
    using EnumBuilderBase<eb_type, eb_enum>::operator =;                                               \
    EB_GENERATE_ENUMERATORS(eb_type, eb_enum, __VA_ARGS__)                                             \
    constexpr size_t Count() const noexcept                                                            \
    {                                                                                                  \
        return static_cast<size_t>(EB_COUNT_VA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__));                                     \
    }                                                                                                  \
    const char* ToString(const ToStringMode mode) const noexcept override                              \
    {                                                                                                  \
        return ToStringWorker(mode, names, sizeof(names) / sizeof(const char*));                       \
    }                                                                                                  \
    const EnumBuilderEnumerator<eb_type, eb_enum> Enumerator(const char* name) const noexcept override \
    {                                                                                                  \
        return EnumeratorWorker(name, #eb_enum"::", names, sizeof(names) / sizeof(const char*));       \
    }                                                                                                  \
private:                                                                                               \
    static inline constexpr const char* names[] = {                                                    \
        EB_FOR_EACH_FA1(EB_GENERATE_NAMES_PAIR, eb_enum, __VA_ARGS__)                                  \
        "ClosingDummy"                                                                                 \
    };                                                                                                 \
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Struct that wraps an enumerator. It gives us tools to control type-safety.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Forward declaration, needed for friend declaration inside 'EnumBuilderEnumerator'.
template<class T = int, class E = void>
struct EnumBuilderBase;

// Wrapper for the enumerator.
template<class T, class E> requires std::integral<T>
struct EnumBuilderEnumerator {
    static inline constexpr T invalid_value = static_cast<T>(-1);

    // Class 'EnumBuilderBase' is a friend.
    template<typename Tf, typename Ef>
    friend struct EnumBuilderBase;

    // Get the value.
    T Value() const noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }

    // Checks if the enumerator has a valid value.
    bool IsValid() const noexcept
    {
        return value != invalid_value;
    }

    // Conversion operator, used for static_cast.
    explicit operator T() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

    // Comparison.
    auto operator <=> (const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return value <=> other.value;
    }
    bool operator == (const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return value == other.value;
    }

    // Stream operator (only output-stream, as 'EnumBuilderEnumerator' is a constexpr in our enums).
    friend static std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& v) noexcept
    {
        return os << v.value;
    }
private:

    // Private, so only friend 'EnumBuilderBase' can use them.
    explicit constexpr EnumBuilderEnumerator(const T value) noexcept : value(value) {}
    T value;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Code for the enum-struct baseclass. This provides:
// 
//    - the actual value for an enum-variable
//    - constructors
//    - assignment operators
//    - stream operators
//    - conversions between string/value
//    - plus some other things
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class T, class E>
struct EnumBuilderBase {

    // Stream-mode.
    enum class StreamMode {
        Value,           // Read/write the value.
        EnumeratorOnly,  // Write string like 'Enumerator', no effect on read.
        IncludeEnumName  // Write string like 'MyEnum::Enumerator', no effect on read.
    };

    // ToString-mode.
    enum class ToStringMode {
        EnumeratorOnly,  // Return string like 'Enumerator'.
        IncludeEnumName  // Return string like 'MyEnum::Enumerator'.
    };

    // Constructors.
    EnumBuilderBase(const T v) noexcept : value(v), mode(StreamMode::Value) {}
    EnumBuilderBase(const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& e) noexcept : value(e.value), mode(StreamMode::Value) {}

    // Must be overridden by the derived class.
    virtual const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E> Enumerator(const char* name) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual const char* ToString(const ToStringMode mode) const noexcept                  = 0;

    // Conversion operator, used for static_cast.
    explicit operator T() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

    // Consider all assignment operators as 'not allowed'.
    template<class U>
    void operator = (const U) = delete;

    // Assignment operators that are allowed.
    void operator = (const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& v) noexcept
    {
        value = v.value;
    }
    void operator = (const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& v) noexcept
    {
        value = v.value;
    }
    void operator = (const char* s) noexcept
    {
        value = Enumerator(s).value;
    }

    // Get the value.
    T Value() const noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }

    // Comparison: enum struct and enum struct.
    auto operator <=> (const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return value <=> other.value;
    }
    bool operator == (const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return value == other.value;
    }

    // Comparison: enum struct and value wrapper.
    friend static auto operator <=> (const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& lhs, const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.value <=> rhs.Value();
    }
    friend static bool operator == (const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& lhs, const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.value == rhs.Value();
    }

    // Comparison: value wrapper and enum struct.
    friend static auto operator <=> (const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& lhs, const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.Value() <=> rhs.value;
    }
    friend static bool operator == (const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>& lhs, const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.Value() == rhs.value;
    }

    // Stream-mode setter.
    void SetStreamMode(const StreamMode m) noexcept
    {
        mode = m;
    }

    // Checks if the enum has a valid value.
    bool IsValid() const noexcept
    {
        return value != EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>::invalid_value;
    }
    
    // Stream operators.
    friend static std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& v) noexcept
    {
        if (v.mode == StreamMode::Value)
            return os << v.value;
        else if(v.mode == StreamMode::EnumeratorOnly)
            return os << v.ToString(ToStringMode::EnumeratorOnly);
        return os << v.ToString(ToStringMode::IncludeEnumName);
    }
    friend static std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, EnumBuilderBase<T, E>& v) noexcept
    {
        // Set to invalid first.
        v.value = EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>::invalid_value;

        // Read value.
        if (v.mode == StreamMode::Value)
            return is >> v.value;

        // Read string.
        std::string s;
        is >> s;
        v.value = v.Value(s);
        return is;
    }
protected:
    
    // Worker method for the ToString() method, called by the derived class.
    const char* ToStringWorker(const ToStringMode mode,
                               const char* const names_array[],
                               const int names_count) const noexcept
    {
        size_t index = 2 * static_cast<size_t>(value) + (mode == ToStringMode::EnumeratorOnly ? 0 : 1);
        if (index >= names_count)
            return "invalid";
        return names_array[index];
    }

    // Worker method for the Enumerator() method, called by the derived class.
    static const EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E> EnumeratorWorker(const char* name,
                                                              const char* enum_name,
                                                              const char* const names_array[],
                                                              const int names_count) noexcept
    {
        // Check for a valid pointer.
        if (name == nullptr)
            return EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>(EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>::invalid_value);

        // Skip the enum name in the string ('enum_name::value_name' becomes 'value_name').
        const char* name_org = name;
        while (*name == *enum_name) {
            ++name;
            ++enum_name;
        }
        if (*enum_name != '\0')
            name = name_org;

        // Check all names.
        for (int i = 0; i < names_count; i += 2) {
            if (!std::strcmp(name, names_array[i]))
                return EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>(i/2);
        }

        // Nothing found...
        return EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>(EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>::invalid_value);
    }

    // Get an initialized wrapper. The derived class calls this method because it cannot
    // directly call the private ctor of 'EnumBuilderEnumerator'.
    static constexpr EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E> GetWrappedValue(const T v) noexcept
    {
        return EnumBuilderEnumerator<T, E>(v);
    }
private:

    // Determines if we read/write a value or a string from/to a stream.
    StreamMode mode;

    // Actual value for enum-variable.
    T value;
};

//----------------------------------------------------
// TEST SECTION.
//----------------------------------------------------

// Create our enums to test with.
ENUM_CLASS_BUILDER(int, SmartEnum, Smaller, Greater)
ENUM_CLASS_BUILDER(int, SmartEnumOther, Smaller, Greater)

// Print a single header-line.
void header_line()
{
    std::cout << "*---------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

// Print a complete header.
void header(const char* s)
{
    header_line();
    std::cout << s;
    header_line();
}

// Test-code.
int main()
{
    SmartEnum smart_s, smart_g;

    // Assignment.
    smart_s = smart_g;
    smart_s = SmartEnum::Smaller;
    smart_g = SmartEnum::Greater;

    // Assignment with a fundamental type.
    // smart_s = 0;      // Error, expected.

    // Convert to a fundamental type.
    // int a = SmartEnum::Smaller;   // Error, expected.
    // int b = smart_s;              // Error, expected.
    int c = static_cast<int>(SmartEnum::Smaller);
    int d = static_cast<int>(smart_s);

    // Number of enumerators.
    header("* Number of enumerators, expected output: 2\n");
    std::cout << smart_s.Count() << "\n\n";

    // Comparison.
    header("* Enum comparison, expected output: 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1\n");
    std::cout << (smart_s == smart_g) << ' ';
    std::cout << (smart_s == SmartEnum::Smaller) << ' ';
    std::cout << (SmartEnum::Smaller == smart_s) << ' ';
    std::cout << (SmartEnum::Smaller == SmartEnum::Greater) << ' ';
    std::cout << (smart_s > smart_g) << ' ';
    std::cout << (smart_g > smart_s) << ' ';
    std::cout << (SmartEnum::Smaller > smart_g) << ' ';
    std::cout << (SmartEnum::Smaller < SmartEnum::Greater) << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Some initializations, and comparison with other enum.
    SmartEnumOther smart_s_other = SmartEnumOther::Smaller;
    SmartEnumOther smart_s_another(SmartEnumOther::Smaller);
    // smart_s            == smart_s_other;             // Error, expected.
    // smart_s            == SmartEnumOther::Smaller;   // Error, expected.
    // SmartEnum::Smaller == SmartEnumOther::Smaller;   // Error, expected.

    // Streams and strings (non-standard functionality).
    header_line();
    std::cout << "* Streams and strings, expected output:\n";
    std::cout << "*     0\n";
    std::cout << "*     1\n";
    std::cout << "*     0\n";
    std::cout << "*     1\n";
    std::cout << "*     Smaller\n";
    std::cout << "*     SmartEnum::Smaller\n";
    std::cout << "*     Smaller\n";
    std::cout << "*     SmartEnum::Smaller\n";
    header_line();
    std::cout << smart_s << '\n';
    std::cout << smart_g << '\n';
    std::cout << SmartEnum::Smaller << '\n';
    std::cout << SmartEnum::Greater << '\n';
    std::cout << smart_s.ToString(SmartEnum::ToStringMode::EnumeratorOnly) << '\n';
    std::cout << smart_s.ToString(SmartEnum::ToStringMode::IncludeEnumName) << '\n';
    smart_s.SetStreamMode(SmartEnum::StreamMode::EnumeratorOnly);
    std::cout << smart_s << '\n';
    smart_s.SetStreamMode(SmartEnum::StreamMode::IncludeEnumName);
    std::cout << smart_s << '\n';
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Assignment with string.
    smart_s.SetStreamMode(SmartEnum::StreamMode::Value);
    header("* String assignment, expected output: -1 0 1\n");
    smart_s = "some invalid string";
    std::cout << smart_s << ' ';
    smart_s = "Smaller";
    std::cout << smart_s << ' ';
    smart_s = "SmartEnum::Greater";
    std::cout << smart_s << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Valid/invalid.
    header("* Valid/invalid, expected output: 0 1\n");
    smart_s = "some invalid string";
    std::cout << smart_s.IsValid() << ' ';
    smart_s = "Smaller";
    std::cout << smart_s.IsValid() << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Get underlying enumerator for a string.
    header("* Enumerator by string, expected output: -1 0 1\n");
    std::cout << smart_s.Enumerator("some invalid string") << ' ';
    std::cout << smart_s.Enumerator("Smaller") << ' ';
    std::cout << smart_s.Enumerator("SmartEnum::Greater") << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}


Just FYI: https://godbolt.org/z/78rbKhG8x

@indi Oof, even with a reflection operator that's an awful amount of code necessary to just to_string() an enum value...

@indi - std::ranges::find_if() seems wrong on a std::map.  It's linear, where std::map::find() is logarithmic, in the size of the map.  (Or perhaps use std::map::at() so the caller gets an exception for out-of-range values).

@indi, I suggest you polish that code and post it for review.

@indi: I would prefer a small lib like yours on top of my ordinary enums instead of the code I wrote, so if you could follow up on Toby's suggestions that would be great. Can you say something about how future proof it is given the experimental meta header? I can't find it here:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental, so it is maybe supported by only a few compilers or even only clang?

I should clarify what the code I posted earlier was. That was not a library; that was standard reflection. That was also not the way real reflection code will probably look when finally finished; that was just what is (basically) already approved… in particular, none of the code injection stuff (like this) is there yet (which is why the code above is so verbose and ugly; I have to “fake” code injection). Also… the code is very probably wrong: I make string views of temporary strings (check in get_string_map_for()). That might be fixable, but… meh.

I would make a demo using code injection with token sequences… which would be much simpler and clearer… except: 1) that spec is much more in flux, and has changed radically in just 2 versions over as many months; and 2) I don’t know any compilers that support it yet (though I heard there is a version of EDG that does). I guess I could show a sample to give a taste, but I doubt I could make it compilable, and I’d have to make a lot of guesses for what the final spec might look like. So… meh.

Also… std::map? I couldn’t use that (or std::string) because it would require non-transient constexpr allocation. That’s why I had to cheat with std::array and std::string_view. A map wouldn’t help much in any case unless it were bi-directional, because I use both the enumerator and the string as keys at different times. I guess you could argue that enum→string lookups are far more common than string→enum lookups and just bite that bullet… but in real code the maps are tiny, and I’ve used tricks to make string parsing much more powerful.

@indi: Ah, I see.... Also your code was highly experimental. Indeed not a situation to spend time on polishing code if the proposals still change much before becoming part of the standard. Thank for your insights though.

You can just use free library magic_enum if you want to convert enums to strings and vice versa. If reflection was already standardised it would be a different situation.

@ALX23z: I know of magic_enum, but thousands of lines of code for my purpose from/to string... In the meantime I found https://wandbox.org/permlink/eMt6MxecI4VoJD9m. It could be a basis for writing a small header that follows the approach of magic_enum: compose a string/value map of an enum on first access which should be possible compile-time, then from/to string is easy.

I use magic_enum for this.

What you have in that wandbox is basically magic_enum. The only tricky part left is how to determine what the enumerators are. Once you have the enumerators, you just have to make an enum↔string map, and the rest is identical to the reflection example. In fact, that’s the only “magic” in the reflection code. Neither to_string() nor from_string() uses reflection, or any trickery. All the reflection used is for getting the enumerators and their string forms in get_string_map_for(). 1/4

So how does magic_enum get the enumerators without reflection? Brute force. Just try every value between numeric_limits<underlying_type_t<E>>::min() and numeric_limits<underlying_type_t<E>>::max() inclusive, and see which ones produce a value string with an enumerator (you might need to limit the range, though, to avoid doing trillions of tests), and build your enum↔string map with that. Without reflection, this is probably the only practical solution, but it’s limited and expensive to compile. 2/4

The only other way I can think of to get the enumerators is basically your method: use a macro to build the enum in the first place, and as a by-product you have the enumerators. However, the way you are doing it—with a variadic macro—is just not the way to go. A “better” solution would probably use X macros. But even that would not be a “good” solution. Frankly, I’d just wait for reflection, and in the meantime manually make enum↔string maps if I have to. (Which is why I posted the reflection example to begin with.) 3/4

What you are doing in the review code is not nearly as flexible, because: 1) you’re not actually making enums, in any sense (just try static_assert(std::is_enum_v<SmartEnum>)); and 2) even if you want to pretend what you’re making is “enum-ish”, you can’t set values for enumerators (vitally important for flags enumerations), and you can’t alias multiple enumerators to the same value (sometimes important). 4/4

@indi: "Frankly, I’d just wait for reflection, and in the meantime manually make enum↔string maps if I have to". That's also my thought now. Keep the existing project code clean, with existing enums, and attach something for now for the string-conversions (something that can easily be replaced when reflection becomes part of C++). Maybe I try to write a 'very-light' magic-enum myself just to learn stuff. It's hobby, not work... Magic enum limits the values from -127 to +127 for the brute-force search, so that's reasonable. I do not assign custom enumerator values, so I could even start at 0.

This inspired me to update some very old code I had that does something similar. I’ve posted it for a review, if you want to check it out. It doesn’t quite solve the problem of stringizing enumerators exactly, but it does sorta-kinda lead in that direction. Hopefully it will help, or at least inspire.

friend functions must not be static
MSVC might allow this, but it's not valid C++ to declare a friend function static: a friend function is not actually part of the class it's declared in, it's rather a convenient way to declare an out-of-class function that has permissions to access the private members of that class. So static doesn't make sense, just remove it. With that, your code also compiles with GCC.
Enable compiler warnings and fix all of them
My compiler warns about several cases of unused variables, initializer lists appearing in the wrong order, and comparisons between signed and unsigned values.
Answers to your questions


What did I miss in trying to mimic enum class behavior (see main())?


It's impossible to completely mimic enum class behavior with a regular class. For one, it would fail std::is_scoped_enum.


What rules did I break, things I forgot, when putting this code together (I do not see myself as a very good programmer, happy when things just work...)?


The code looks pretty good to me, except for the macros, but more on that below. Also:


I read somewhere to use noexcept wherever possible. Is that a correct practice?


No. Only mark a function as noexcept when you are absolutely sure that nothing inside it can throw, otherwise you prevent the caller from catching those exceptions, in which case your program will abort instead of handling an error gracefully. Also, noexcept almost never gives you a performance benefit, so don't add it thinking it makes your program faster.
So, for simple operations like assignment and comparisons of integers, noexcept is fine. However, any function that does I/O with an std::istream or std::ostream can throw, so don't use noexcept for those. Even using a std::string inside a function can cause exceptions to be thrown, for example if memory needs to be allocated for that string and there is not enough memory.
Reduce macros to a minimum
Macros have lots of issues, one of them being hard to read. Always try to reduce their use to a minimum, and do whatever you can using regular C++. We only need macros here because C++ doesn't have reflection yet. So just use it for that. For example, you could use the macro to declare a struct that only holds the name of a type and the names of its members:
template<typename T>
struct EnumInfo;

#define ENUM_CLASS_BUILDER(type_, name_, ...)\
template<>\
struct EnumInfo<name_> {\
    using type = type_;\
    static constexpr const char* name = #name_;\
    static constexpr const char* members[] = {#__VA_ARGS__};\
};\
enum class name_: type_ {__VA_ARGS__};

The above macro will generate a real enum class type, along with an EnumInfo for that type. Now you can write functions to operate directly on the enum type, for example:
template<typename T>
std::ostream& print_enum(std::ostream& os, const T& value) {
    using Info = EnumInfo<T>;
    return os << Info::name << "::" << Info::members[std::to_underlying(value)];
}

But if you want to just have a class that looks like an enum, you could write something like:
template<typename EnumInfo>
class EnumBuilderBase {
    …
    EnumInfo::type value;
};

#define ENUM_CLASS_BUILDER(type_, name_, ...)\
struct EnumInfo_ ## name_ {\
    using type = type_;\
    static constexpr const char* name = #name_;\
    static constexpr const char* members[] = {#__VA_ARGS__};\
};\
using name_ = EnumBuilderBase<EnumInfo_ ## name_>;

For simplicity I wrote {#__VA_ARGS__} in the above code, but of course #__VA_ARGS__ doesn't expand to multiple strings, so you can either split that string in plain C++ (possibly even fully at compile-time), or use EB_EXPAND() to do it.
